# How to check time difference in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel to develop API, i was stuck at one point calculating time difference between two time stamps .my database is present in another region and my machine running on UTC timing so i could not able to find exact time difference between two time stamps ,is there any way to check timestamp in the query level itself i have tried with **TIMESTAMPDIFF()** but it's not working as expected

```
$childdata = $childConnection->query("select useractivitytime,idfrom userdetails where status = 0");

 $current_date_time = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); // this gives me the application running time.
 $difference_in_seconds = strtotime($current_date_time) - strtotime($value['js_useractivity']); //result in seconds.
```

Comment: if its for only dev purpose then use laravel debugbar (package) it shows infos relating to query including execution time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`TIMEDIFF`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp):

```
select 
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), useractivitytime)) AS difference_in_seconds, 
  id 
from 
  userdetails 
where 
  status = 0
```

Comment: @Ipizzinidev ,NOW() function should take server region time only right ?

Comment: @TestTest According to the docs, it takes the session time zone. For more see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now